# Sort by values of properties on Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have an object like this:

[image: object in JavaScript]

I would like to do two things.

1. Sort the properties based on their values
2. I would to know the order (or index) for any given property. For example, after ordering, I would like to know that the index of `00D` is the **5th**.

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/umidjons/9614157

Comment: Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can not sort properties of an object, you could use an array of keys of the object, sort them and take the wanted element, you want.

```
var keys = Object.keys(object),     // get all keys
    indices = Object.create(null);  // hash table for indices

// sort by value of the object
keys.sort(function (a, b) { return object[a] - object[b]; });

// create hash table with indices
keys.forEach(function (k, i) { indices[k] = i; });

// access the 5th key
console.log(keys[5]);

// get index of 00G
console.log(indices['00G']);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, but I am after the index number. I want to supply `00G` and get its Index. Also I believe you're sorting the `keys` there, not the `values` which is what I'm after.